# How to prevent Android app from running on specific Android API version?

Tags: android

We know that uses-sdk attributes in the manifest file can be set for filtering on Google Play:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
      android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
      android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

and **android:minSdkVersion** can prevent app from installing on Android OS.

However **android:maxSdkVersion** is deprecated from Android 2.1 (API7), so it won't be recognized by Android OS anymore.

Then, what is the best way to set an upper limit of Android API version for running an app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an app not to be downloaded by Android KitKat users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278293/how-to-make-an-app-not-to-be-downloaded-by-android-kitkat-users)

Comment: That question is about "not to be downloaded", android:maxSdkVersion is enough to do the task, but mine is not to run on Android OS.

Comment: check the OS version in your MainActivity and promt user if the os is not supported ;)

Comment: Maybe I can do like this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21100068/4176421) and show a alert dialog as [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25278596/4176421) mentioned. But no other ways?